# supportedChain is deprecated, please pass networks instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, solidity

I am at the final lesson and I get an error in my localhost console:

```
supportedChain is deprecated, please pass networks instead
useConfig @ context.ts:23
```

At first I thought it might have something to do with my code, but I copy pasted all of the code out of the github and I still got the message. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Also, I get the following parsing error:

```
Failed to parse source map from '/mnt/c/users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@metamask/detect-provider/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/c/users/user/documents/blockchain/sizzlingstaking/front_end/node_modules/@metamask/detect-provider/src/index.ts'
```

Is that a package issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a tutorial which I encounter the same issue.

It is indeed that supportedChain is deprecated. You may migrate to using networks to eliminate the error. Following snippet provides an example.

```
import { DAppProvider, Kovan, Rinkeby } from '@usedapp/core'; // import desired network
function App() {
  return (
    <DAppProvider config={{
       networks: [Kovan, Rinkeby]
    }}>
        ...
    </DAppProvider>
)
```

Sources and references:
https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/core/

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/issues/1283

Comment: Hi, that link returns a page not found error, do you know the updated link? That'd be really helpful :)